# How to the solve issues NoLinkedYouTubeAccount in an IOS custom app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I created an iPhone application to integrate YouTube API using Gdata static file.In the iPhone application login with gmail account an upload video on YouTube account. The problem is that some gmail account it uploading successfully but some gmail account it show error message "failedWithStatus:401 data:NoLinkedYouTubeAccount"

Please let me know how to solve above problen in custom iPhone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing to YouTube with Gmail account, you must first **create the channel** in your YouTube account when signed in with your Gmail account.

How create the channel on YouTube :  http://support.google.com/youtube/

Comment: then I should creating each gmail account separeted channge in each youtube account?

Comment: 1 gmail - 1 youtube account (if logged in with google)
You need some workaround to determine if people logins with google and they have not created their channel.

Comment: I just want to the user can login gmail account and upload video on youtube using my iPhone application. My problem is that if user have not created their channel then what can i do?

Comment: the easiest way - alert message "channel must be created " with some sort of link to youtube and instructions.

You could load web youtube in a browser or in a webview

Creating a channel name on m.youtube.com:
On your iPhone, go to m.youtube.com in your iPhone’s browser.
Press Sign in located at the bottom of the home page and sign in with your YouTube account information.
Press Menu.
To create your channel name, touch any of the following: Favorites, Playlists, My Videos, Inbox.